# What is the difference between [友達]{とも・だち} and [友人]{ゆう・じん}?

Tags: meaning, wago-and-kango

From a quick google search, they both refer to **friend**.

Are they completely identical or is there any difference between [友達]{とも・だち} and [友人]{ゆう・じん}?

Comment: there was an interesting discussion about this question in the [jisho forum](http://forum.jisho.org/discussion/638/how-would-you-wirte-the-plural-of-%E5%8F%8B%E9%81%94tomodachi-/p1). A lot of the answers seem to conflict with each other though...

Comment: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/8806/m0u/%E5%8F%8B%E4%BA%BA/

Comment: 友人 is more formal. Nothing to back this up, but my sense is that it also can be a more distant relationship.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's just that 友人 is more formal than 友達. I don't feel there is any difference in what they refer to.

For example, saying 「友人が会社を経営していまして。。。」 in a job interview would sound natural, but saying「友達が会社を経営していまして。。。」 sounds a bit childish. Conversely, 「ずっと友人でいような！」is weird but 「ずっと友達でいような！」 is natural.

Answer (score 11):

友人 is more formal than 友達.

I think this formality results in the side effect of it suggesting a closer friendship, because one would usually not refer to someone as a friend in Japanese in a serious conversation if they were not close, in my opinion.

So no, they are not identical — there are situations where one makes more sense to use than the other — but as far as understanding goes, I don't think it really matter if you ignore that specific nuance.

Comment: I've added the phrase "in Japanese" into your first paragraph, I hope that doesn't misunderstand the sense of what you were trying to say.