# What are the different use cases for 家 vs. 自宅

Tags: word-choice, kanji, nuances

So far, in my very simple conversations I've used 家{うち} to talk about my home. Now I've seen 自宅{じたく} as well and I'm wondering about the differences, nuances, and use cases of these two words when referring to my own home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual, being a [漢語](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18365/5010), 自宅 tends to be used in formal and/or technical contexts.  You will mainly see 自宅 on various written documents and forms.

In casual conversations, 家 is preferred. Inviting your friend to your home saying 自宅に来てよ would sound a bit strange.

Comment: Imagine the difference between 'come to my house!' and 'come to my residence!'.