# How can I differentiate if a word is (either fully or preferentially) used for spoken or written language?

Tags: spoken-language, wago-and-kango, written-language

Sorry if this has been answered before, but I couldn't find it.

I understand that when the on'yomi reading is used, this is associated with words with a more "literary" feeling or with written usage. However, I don't know if this is a relatively safe way to differentiate which usage is preferred of if it's just applied in some cases.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please beware that questions asking for tools and resources are considered off-topic here. Therefore, at least a part of your question is out of the scope of this site. However, I still think that your question can be reframed to fit here (e.g. "How to differentiate between a word used in spoken language and a word used in written language" or such). Would you mind to rephrase it? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are 漢語 always more formal than 和語？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18365/are-%e6%bc%a2%e8%aa%9e-always-more-formal-than-%e5%92%8c%e8%aa%9e)

Comment: Provide some examples!

Comment: I can't think of anything from the top of my head, but usually, in Japanese class, when we had to do a small composition, I would have to look up a couple of words I didn't know, and sometimes the teacher would say "OK, I understand the meaning but that word is mostly for spoken language", or vice-versa. So I don't know if it is directly linked to formality, and thus solvable with kango/wago, or if it's something you just learn with practice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert myself, but I asked a few Japanese people about this, and the answer I got is that there is no actual rule. You either have to check in a dictionary or try using the word and watch if people are surprised by what you said. There seems to be a general trend, that the less hiragana and the more strokes in a kanji, it's usually not a word for casual conversation, though keep in mind, it's just a hint, and not a rule.