# Why would a Japanese adult be embarrassed to use the word "friends"?

Tags: word-choice, anime

I am watching a current anime, *That Time I Got Reincarnated as a Slime* ( 転生したらスライムだった件 ). The protagonist, now a reincarnated slime in the isekai story, is making friends with a dragon.  The specific conversation begins at time code 20:30 of [chapter 1](https://www.crunchyroll.com/that-time-i-got-reincarnated-as-a-slime/episode-1-the-storm-dragon-veldora-777519)*. After they have agreed to be friends, he thinks to himself (sub, time code 21:17):

> いい年して『友達』って、ちょっと照れるけど…。
>   It's a little embarrassing talking about "friends" at my age...

He was 37 when murdered.  **Why would he be embarrassed to use the word "friends"?**  Is there a better word to be used between adults?

---

<sub>* Link is to Crunchyroll, an American streaming service.  I don't know what other countries will be able to view it.</sub>

<sub>This question is a follow-up to [What is Japanese version of the pun word, “slife”? … and term for adult friend?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49183/what-is-japanese-version-of-the-pun-word-slife-and-term-for-adult-friend/49192). On Anime & Manga SE. @кяαzєя answered it, and he suggested I post a follow-up question here.</sub>

Comment: People living in Japan can watch this episode here: https://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/so33950614 (official and free)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> いい年して「友達【ともだち】」って、ちょっと照れるけど。

The word *tomodachi* ("friend") itself is not really embarrassing, although there is a more [formal word](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18312/5010) for this concept. In this case, this *tomodachi* also represents the whole exchange he has just made with the tsundere dragon. Indeed, innocently and directly saying 友達にならないか ("Let's be friends!") is not something a typical middle-aged man would do, at least in Japan.  It sounds to me like what a kindergartner might say. Usually such a relationship between adults starts without mentioning the word *tomodachi*. (By the way, the situation is different [when it comes to romantic relationship](https://www.tofugu.com/japan/kokuhaku-love-confessing-japan/).)

Comment: Thank you; that makes sense.  I understand what you mean about an adult suggesting, "Let's be friends" within minutes of meeting another adult.  Even in American culture that I don't believe it is a common occurrence. BTW, I up-voted your answer, someone else down-voted within minutes. Not that the points will make any difference to you. :)

Comment: 37 is middle-aged?!?! Man, I must be positively *ancient*...